# Revolution slider bullets always stuck at first bullet

Tags: wordpress

I am using the revolution slider, the slider is working properly but the bullets are not working properly. even if slide move to next slide still bullet goes to first bullet, whereas it has to stop on second bullet.

Comment: You should provide some code, we can't help you if we can't reproduce.

Comment: Unless you provide a live URL or a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code so we can inspect it, there's nothing much we can do with the information you have provided so far. Please share more details so we can help.

Comment: Can you add you site url please?

Comment: my site url is http://www.umadii.co/studio-id/   the banner is working fine but if you see banner bullets it is not working properly